Any ROS2 package for OpenPcdet?
I have been using OpenPCDet (https://github.com/open-mmlab/OpenPCDet) for 3D object detection on LiDAR data. I found some GitHub repositories that provide ROS packages for OpenPCDet, and I'm wondering if there is a ROS2 package available for this purpose.
I'm aware of the NVIDIA TAO Toolkit for ROS2 PointPillars, but it requires a lot of dependencies and is limited to PointPillars for 3D object detection. In contrast, OpenPCDet offers more options for 3D object detection.
I appreciate any help in advance.
Abbas
